# Flash AS3/Mouse position between startDrag and stopDrag

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, mousemove, onmousemove

I have a 'drag item' and some 'drop target' so I want to highlight drop target while 'drag item' is dragging so need to track mouse position or listen the mouse move event. I try subscribe ENTER_FRAME event and do hit test but wonder there's any solution for this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   //Do your thing here
   e.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

Note that if you're listening for start/stop drag then you should add/remove the MOUSE_MOVE listener when the start/stop events take place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't prefer use stage mouse move event but I will mark this answer is acceptable.